# Focus de Color Negro en vez del color De fault

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, native

Hay algo que no estoy entendiendo bien y es lo siguiente:
Estoy utilizando react native y native base para el manejo de inputs.
Sucede que al seleccionar el texto dsede mi dispositivo android lo marca de esta manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo marca con un fondo negro horrible y no lo marca de forma predeterminada como en otras apps.

La parte de mi input es esta:

```
<Input
            value={email}
            selectionColor="white"
            onChangeText={(value) => setEmail(value)}
            variant="rounded"
            w={{
              base: '75%',
              md: '30%',
            }}
            InputLeftElement={
              <Icon
                name="mail"
                size={30}
                style={{ marginLeft: 10, color: '#4F8EF7' }}
              />
            }
            placeholder="Email"
          />
```

Trate de leer la documentación y investigar por mi parte, pero las soluciones como el "selectionColor="white" no me funcionaron correctamente.

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

Answer (score 0):

```js
< Input
value = {
  email
}
selectionColor = "white"
onChangeText = {
  (value) => setEmail(value)
}
variant = "rounded"
w = {
  {
    base: '75%',
    md: '30%',
  }
}
bg = "white" // Agrega esta línea para establecer el color de fondo como blanco
InputLeftElement = { <
  Icon
  name = "mail"
  size = {
    30
  }
  style = {
    {
      marginLeft: 10,
      color: '#4F8EF7'
    }
  }
  />
}
placeholder = "Email" /
  >
```

Comment: Hola Xavier, bienvenido, gracias por tu colaboración, las respuesta que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos, ver como responder, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de Bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Comment: De donde obtuviste esta informaciòn bg no se usa.